# How to convert the table() to a data.frame?

Tags: r

I have a 6x6 matrix:

```
M = matrix(0,nrow = 6, ncol = 6);
for(i in 1:6)
  for(j in 1:6)
    M[i,j]<- i+j

> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    2    3    4    5    6    7
[2,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[3,]    4    5    6    7    8    9
[4,]    5    6    7    8    9   10
[5,]    6    7    8    9   10   11
[6,]    7    8    9   10   11   12
```

I am using table() function to build a contingency table of the counts at each combination of factor levels.

table(M)

output:

```
> table(M)
M
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Now I want to convert the table(M) to a data.frame using following:

```
pmfY <- data.frame(table(M))
```

But the pmfY$M changes to the follwong:

```
> pmfY$M
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

I am expecting pmfY$M to be the following vector in data frame.

```
2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Why pmfY$M is changed when converting table(M) to data frame and how to fix it?

Comment: For constructing M: `outer(1:6, 1:6, "+")`.

Comment: `stack(table(M))`

Comment: `data.frame(as.list(table(M)))`

Comment: `2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 ` are the _names_ of the columns in the table. `data.frame` uses the _values_. If you really want what you said,  use `pmfY <- names(table(M))`.  Although it might be easier to use `unique(as.vector(M))
`

Comment: So how do I create a data.frame with the numeric arrays of the name and the corresponding frequencies? I want to do further mathematical manipulation on names and freq vectors?

Comment: See the comment of @bouncyball  `stack(table(M))`

Comment: Got it. Just for FYI, I converted factor to numerics for further mathematical operations using pmfY$ind <- as.numeric(as.character(pmfY$ind))